# Reopening in a Container in Vscode - git issue

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-devcontainer, remote-containers

I have a project with a .devcontainer folder with appropriate setup files. So, through Vscode I can open the project in a docker container with the configured environment for development and testing. But when I open it in a container all the files in the project are tagged as Modified. But when I change any file, save it, and open it locally then only that file is modified.

I'm not sure why this is happening and is this expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the answer and the issue was with different line endings conversion between Windows(local env) and the docker container.
Using the following and cloning the repo again resolved the issue.

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

A detailed discussion is in the link below:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_resolving-git-line-ending-issues-in-containers-resulting-in-many-modified-files